# Azure ServiceBus Queue: Consumer Application

Tags: .net, azure, message-queue, service-bus

I am running a .net MVC4 web application. I want to be able to hit an action on a controller, create an email and send it to my service bus queue to be processed (sent).

What are my options as far as creating a consumer for my queue?

I've considered creating another project that runs when the web app is started that continually checks the queue state and processes messages as they come in.

I was wondering if there were any other solutions to processing messages.

Answer (score 1):

A second project that checks the queue and process messages is what I would do. Background processing [belongs to background workers](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/).

Just remember that you don't have to continuously monitor the queue, if you are using a Service Bus queue: plain Azure queues are non-blocking, but Service Bus queues offer blocking receive operations which block the calling thread until a message arrives on a queue or a specified timeout period has elapsed.

So you just have to call your receive function in a loop, and it will stay there and wait for the next call.
You can read the initial paragraphs of [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh697709.aspx): it is about performances, which is not your case, but the initial overview is good for grasping the fundamentals.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Lorenzo. I'll take a look at the articles you referenced. I spoke with some of my colleagues and they said that an azure worker role may also be a viable option. I'll take your suggestion into consideration. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, definitely! I naturally assumed that when you talked about "a second project" you meant an Azure worker role, not another Web project/Azure web role. My bad for making this assumption, I should have been clearer